# Resume listener after kafka restart

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka listener/consumer application(spring-kafka based) running.

If, for any reason, I restart kafka, my listener is not getting any messages, until I restart the consumer application. Is there anything I need to do, so that consumer can continue to get messages, without restarting the application?

Comment: Kafka defaults to store data in /tmp. If you restart that server, it'll delete everything

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, because "this is not supposed to happen(tm)" - Kafka is designed in a way for which you may stop one or more nodes at the time, as long as you are able to maintain a quorum.

You should not bring the whole cluster down together (unless you talk about a dev instance).

For this reason, I would also recommend that you place client and Kafka clusters on the same physical network, so that you maximise throughput and minimise the risk of network partitions.